# I have 2 flows/actions that require file upload. Can I have a common file upload action to support both flows without composition?

Tags: java, file-upload, playframework

Here's my thought process:

- There are some things I need to always to when a file is uploaded,
  like validation and persisting the file.
- Some of these, like persisting, are responsibilities of the model (or
  service, depending on your code organization).
- Others, like validation, I prefer to have in the action layer.
  However, I don't want to duplicate this validation logic across all
  actions that use file uploads.

I could use action composition and wrap my flow actions around a file handler action using @With, but intercepting file uploads does not feel like the right way.

Is there any pattern which lets me do something like this:

1. The main action, say editProfile, is called.
2. This action delegates the upload-related responsibilities to a
   shared action, uploadFile, which performs validation and then calls
   into the model/service to execute business logic.
3. The uploadFile action then returns to editProfile and passes along
   information about whether or it was able to do its job successfully.

If I'm going down the wrong path, what's the right place to house validation such that it's available across actions and has access to the request context?

Comment: It's a good idea to share some sample code that helps explain what your current solution looks like.

Comment: Why does the upload code have to be an action? Do you want to use it as an action? If you just want to call it from other actions I'd put it in a service class. Apart from that I think the pattern you have is quite fine.